# Magento2 Notification messages

Tags: magento2, global-messages

In Magento2, how do we print the input data into notification messages for
- Error
- Success
- Warning
- Notice

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using a controller, then most probably you have extended

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php

This injects the `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` object in its `__construct` function using the `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context` object

So to display a message,

1. Success  -

   $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                   __('This is your success message.')
               );
2. Error -

   $this->messageManager->addError(
                   __('This is your error message.')
               );
3. Warning -

   $this->messageManager->addWarning(
                   __('This is your warning message.')
               );
4. Notice

   $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                   __('This is your notice message.')
               );

Inside other classes

```
class Dummy
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
   private $messageManager;

   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager)
   {
       $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
   }

  public function someFunction()
  {
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Add your success message');
  }

}
```

So as far as i have noticed, Magento2 has removed session class specific notification messages.

Comment: Magento has deprecated these add<type>() methods. See my answer.

Comment: I have a problem with message, when I add to cart it show success message but when I access to another page it still show that message. How can I remove it when it show at least once time?

Answer (score 43):

In your class, inject the Message ManagerInterface class:

```
protected $messageManager;

__construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager) {
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}
```

Note, Magento has **deprecated methods**:

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess()
$this->messageManager->addError()
$this->messageManager->addWarning() 
$this->messageManager->addNotice()
```

So instead you should use:

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage()
$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage()
$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage() 
$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage()
```

Comment: Would this also work during the onepage checkout, where "everything" is javascript?

Comment: Apparently the "page.messages" section gets removed from the checkout through the checkout_index_index.xml file, so messages will not be shown there. I wonder why Magento built it that way.