# Magento2 - show/notify customer when they reach x in the cart to spend x more to get free item or discount

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, promotional-banner

Basically I am looking If there is something out there or anyone has used anything or suggestions for when in a cart price rule where the rules is E.G: **spend $100 and get Y for FREE.**

So It's basically a near miss, so when they reach their basket total let say $90 as a minimum threshold then either as a popup message at product page or cart page etc... to let then know if they spend $10 more to get Y item for free so basically let them know about the promotion.

I've seem some web comm do this.

The reason being as some customer might not be aware of the promotion but yet we don't want to place banner and notices everywhere clustering the  website this will also make the process more automated and no needing to remove promotional tex, banners. images etc...

I've been researching the web but couldn't find anything!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by checking basket total amount while adding product to the basket and below some points that will help you.
1. Create an event observer on event **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** (For more details check [Add to cart after event in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213754/add-to-cart-after-event-in-magento2)).
2. Check for condition, basket amount with a minimum amount (eg. 90).
3. If your condition true then you can handle/display a message with the help of MessageMessanger (For more details check [Magento2 Notification messages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87972/magento2-notification-messages)).
4. The minimum amount will be saved in system configuration (dynamic price).

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I thought of this initiative, However I though that it would have an extension for this already out there. Your point 2 needs more then checking condition on basket level It needs to check if there is a promotion active/setup etc... I'll keep looking but I think my last resort is to custom build a module for it!

Comment: Yes, you can check condition on basket level for active promotion rules, I don't think so that ready extension available that cover all your points.

Comment: @ManishBhojwani Can your check this, and tell how we can achieve the discount price
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/345172/discount-the-cart-price-which-product-price-magento-2-4-2-ce