# Discount the cart price which product price - Magento 2.4.2 CE

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, price-rules

I need to discount the line item's total price in the total when the particular product is added to the cart.  How to implement can get any suggestion.
Eg:
Product A added to the cart at the qty of 5 and its price is 20INR and the line item total is 5 * 20 = 100 INR
I need to discount the 100INR in the subtotal or total at Magento.

I had checked this in cart price but it is not working for the particular product.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Cart Price Rule select **Apply**="**Fixed Amount Discount**" and within the "**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions**" - section you have to select the Product A e.g. by providing the SKU.

[image]

To have the SKU available here, you may activate first "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" within the Product Attribute > Storefront Properties

Comment: The fixed amount will reduce the fixed price but I need to reduce the particular product's line items price in discount.

Answer (score 0):

@Msquare

You can add discounts to a particular product by using the default Magento feature of Product Tier Pricing.

Refer the link for the detailed information:
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-tier-price-in-magento-2.html

Comment: using the product discount rule will change the product price to 0 in the cart page the product line item price must be show as discounted for me.